# How to get multiple data from passing same ids using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I Have a problem with getting data from the database.
Actually, I want multiple data from the database with passing multiple same ids using IN  in MySQL.
Like 
table
[image]

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,1,2)
```

I need result with five records.

OUTPUT like,

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking can you add sample data and expected output as text.

Comment: In below reult integer value is id, For ex. 1 is primary key and HTML is other field value of id 1.     Result like, 1:HTML, 2:CSS, 3:PHP, 1:HTML,2:CSS

Comment: Restating the result you want without describing the logic of how you get there isn't going to move this question forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` to limit the results to only 5 records and use `ORDER BY FIELD` to get the desired order. Here's a snippet:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1, 2, 3) LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: If there are 5 1s then you may only 5 ones back with this query

Comment: He stated this: ```I need result with five records.```. He wants only 5 records for any given data.

Comment: @Sarah Dominguez Perea It's the wrong way to do that, We have dynamic record So it's not fixed for 5 records only some time query like, WHERE id IN(1,2,2,3,1)

Comment: Sorry my bad. Question's a little unclear though. We were confused with this statement in the question ```I need result with five records.```. :( I think the question needs more details, sample input and output, as stated in the comments. Sorry and thanks.